# Loading game levels in JavaScript w/o back-end

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a Javascript game, simple one. I want to store game levels on my server but not load all of them at once, but rather load then when they're needed, asynchronously.

I don't have any back-end host (no PHP etc.), but I can keep my levels in any kind of file (text, image, js script file).

What's a good solution to loading levels?

Comment: How is a Level structured? what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't decided yet - I know what the level must contain (it's a 2d platformer game), but how it will be saved and served is to be yet decided - depending on Javascript capabilities

Comment: ok, i put a possible solution in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would prefer JS (JSON), because you have a native JSON Parser onboard and you can easy test it. 
You can use any other format with XHR (XMLHttpRequest/Ajax).
You could also use XHR on local files (http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&p=6033635).

This is a Example Class `LevelLoader` that loads JSON over XHR.

```
if ( typeof gamens== 'undefined') {
    var gamens= {};
}

gamens.LevelLoader = function() {
       this.leveldata = {};
};

gamens.LevelLoader.prototype = {

    fromString : function(data) {
        this.leveldata = JSON.parse(data);
        // this.repaint();
    },

    fromFile : function(name) {
            var xmlhttp = xhr();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "level/" + name + ".js", true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    this.fromString(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
};


var loader = new gamens.LevelLoader(); 
// load "level/test.js"  
// example: 
// {"tiles":[0,1,1]}
loader.fromFile("test"); 
console.log(loader.leveldata);
```

The xhr function that returns an XMLHttpRequest Object:

```
var xhr = function() {
    var _xhr = false;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            _xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                _xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (ex) {
                _xhr = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!_xhr && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        try {
            _xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            _xhr = false;
        }
    }
    if (!_xhr && window.createRequest) {
        try {
            _xhr = window.createRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            _xhr = false;
        }
    }
    return _xhr;    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). It allows you to load additional info from server without page refresh. How you will store it on server - depends on you. You just need those files to be accessible with some URL.
It simply allows to download any piece of data (JSON/text/HTML/XML) from server asynchronously and use it in your JS code.

As for me, the best would be to use JSON format in order to store levels info on server as it could be converted to JS object easily.